# Not able to pass form information to a FormHandler cloudpage which is located in parent (different) BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, parameters

I have a cloudPage with a form and i need the values to be stored in a DataExtension in current BU and then pass the values to a FormHandler Page which is stored in another BU (same Account)

1. I want to save form data in a Data Extension
2. Want to pass the form data to the FormHandler page in different BU page to process it there

When Using:

"`form" action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%"` The data is saved into the Data Extension but i do not have the option to pass the data to the FormHandler Cloudpage.

When iam Using:

```
%%[ SET @FirstName = "InputFirstName"
    IF Not Empty(@FirstName) Then
       Redirect(ConCat('http://www.google.com&FirstName=',@FirstName))
    EndIF
]%%
```

The FirstName can not be fetched on the Formhandler Page. Does somebody have an idea why the data is not send to the Formhandler page?

In addition to that to fetch the parameters is the function QueryParameter or RequestParameter the right one on the Formhandler Page?

Comment: How are you fetching the first name in your from handler, what function are you using? Also, you need to move the function to save data in a DE to your form handler.

Comment: Hi zuzannamj In the formhandler iam using this:

 %%[ 
     SET @Name = QueryParameter("FirstName")
  ]%% 

  FirstName = %%=V(@Name)=%%

Just to see if any value is passed to the formhandler. I although tried RequestParameter instead of QueryParameter


Yes once i can pass the data i will add the Inserde function on the formhandler Page.

Comment: Everything seems to be good in ur AMPscript.... also as you are passing value in URL you are good with QueryParameter  function... just checking you are replacing `http://www.google.com` with ur cloudPage URL which is in another BU

Comment: Hello @vishal-kumar-c-v
Thank you, it it is working now. I replaced google url with the URL of the cloudpage in parent BU. Seems my syntax had some errors.

But:

Iam currently try to do the same from an email. Passing subsciber values from Email into a DIFFERENT BU. I assuemed that it works similar i used: 

Redirectto('http: / /mc.xxxx.xx&SubcriberKey=',@SubscriberKey,FirstName=',@FirstName)

Unfortunately it is not working. When i test with a cloudpage in same BU and using CloudpageURL function it is working fine. DO you have any idea?

Comment: I am NOT sure whether its a Typo, but NOTE that [RedirectTo](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) takes only 1 parameter ... so please use as below and check `<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat('https://mc.xxxx.xx?SubcriberKey=',@SubscriberKey,'&FirstName=',@FirstName))=%%">Click me</a>`